# Install Android SDK without Studio on Linux for Qt Creator

Tags: android, linux, qt, qt-creator

Android Studio does not start on my machine with a warning about unsufficient memory. So I want to work on Android apps with Qt Creator. Unfortunately Google decided to make it harder to just get the Android SDK and refers to Android Studio, so all older tutorials link to dead pages or to pages that are redirected to the Android Studio website.

So what are the steps needed to install the plain SDK, the NDK and enable Qt Creator for Android development?

I documented the steps I took to make it work and will post them in an answer hoping they will be halpful for other people as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how it works in February 2017.

- Download the *Android SDK command line tools* from the link at the bottom end of https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
- Unzip. Note that you need to leave the folder name untouched (`tools/`), otherwise it will not work. I have it unpacked as `/usr/local/Android/android-sdk/tools` creating the folders `Android/` and `android-sdk/` and then unzip into `android-sdk/`.
- Run `./android` from the `tools/` folder. A GUI is spawning where you can select SDK stuff to be installed. Of course there is also a newer version of the SDK tools available than the one you just downloaded two minutes ago. ;)
- Select the Android version of your device (you can probably deselect the Intel-based sub packages and Android TV stuff from that version, so check the contents of the packages you select. If in doubt, install them, though. :) ... The installation process will take some time.
- Download the Android NDK from https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html
- Unzip. According to my SDK tools folder, I chose to unzip the NDK into `/usr/local/Android/` as `android-ndk/`.
- In Qt Creator go to the Settings dialog (`Tools -> Settings...`) and there to `Devices -> Android` and fill in the locations of your SDK and NDK. Note: for the SDK you need to state the folder *containing* the `tools/` folder, not the `tools/` folder itself. So for me:

  - `/usr/local/Android/android-sdk`
  - `/usr/local/Android/android-ndk`
- Add some SDK and NDK paths to your shell's rc file, e.g. `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc`:

  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Android/android-sdk/tools

  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Android/android-sdk/platform-tools

  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Android/android-ndk

Now you should be good to go. ... For me on one system the QtCreator kits were created automatically on another they weren't. Not sure why. If needed, you can create the kits manually and be done. :)